# Success Message as a model in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model

I intend to reuse success message in my MVC web application as a model, and this model could be a part of another model to report feedback status during data modification. So far, I can't get this working. Say I have FeedbackMessage object as model below to reflect success message:

```
public class FeedbackMessage
{
    public string Message { get; private set; }
    public FeedbackType Type { get; private set; } // 'info', 'error', 'warning', 'success'
    public string Image { get; }
}
```

and I have a user preference page which uses Preference object as the model and this object has FeedbackMessage as folowing

```
public class Preference
{
    public string DisplayName { get; set;}
    public string BlogUrl { get; set; }
    public FeedbackMessage FeedbackMessage { get; set; }
    public bool IsValid { get; set; }
}
```

and in my controller, I follow PRG (Post-Redirect-Get) pattern for data modification. The code is briefly as following:

```
public ActionResult Preference()
{
     var model = new Preference();
     model.DisplayName = Models.Settings.Preference.DisplayName;
     ...
     return this.View(model);
}

[HttpPost]
public Action Preference(Preference model)
{
    if (model.IsValid)
    { 
         model.FeedbackMessage = new FeedbackMessage { Type = "success" };
    }
    else
    {
         model.FeedbackMessage = new FeedbackMessage { Type = "failure" };
    }

    ...

    return this.Preference(); // issue Get
}
```

My problem is that I can't get feedback at all after doing POST, since during GET it again initializes Preference object. At this point, I'm reluctant to use TempData as suggested by other stackoverlow thread since it's more explicit and cleaner done in the model.

Could anyone that has experience around this area show/guide me how to fix this or else show me a better design? Thanks.

Comment: It is obvious that you will have to store this feedback somewhere so it could be picked up on the following get request. TempData was designed to support this kind of functionality, So the simplest way will be indeed using TempData. By the way you can store a complex model in TempData (for example your Preference model from your post request) `TempData["Preference"] = model` and then in your get request `Preference postModel = (Preference)TempData["Preference"]`

Comment: Why, if there is a failure, would another `GET` be made? If there is a problem with invalid data, or failed save attempt, then another `GET` should be avoided. Simply return the view in the `HttpPost` action method, with the appropriate viewmodel settings i.e. FeedbackMessage, set. You should perform a `GET` once you're happy all the data is valid, or has been successfully saved.

Comment: It should be `return RedirectToAction("Preference");` not `return this.Preference();` If you don't want to persist the values somewhere (e.g. `TempData`), then you can always pass the value(s) as route parameters - `return RedirectToAction("Preference", new { message = "someValue", .... });` and add the parameters to your GET method.

Comment: @StephenMuecke thanks for the correction of using RedirectToAction. I realized I didn't get http 302 code from my code.

Answer (score 0):

1. Use ajax to post the preference model, then use json to return the result(FeedbackMessage) to client,  and use js to display the feedback
2. Because Post-Redirect-Get across different request, Normally use TempData to save model and display in the next request, but we can do this at base layout view
3. If you don't want to change the code above, you can add a private method whith accept different perfenrence model and return the view action to client. so that reuse the model